# Android & Azure Mobile Service Query: how to halt code execution until query finishes

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I need to know how to halt code execution until my mobile service query finishes. I am getting a null pointer exception because the code is attempting to access the query data before the query finishes.

```
---Code---
mEmployeeTable.execute(new TableQueryCallback<Employee>() {
 //get employees
 ...
});

//In this activity i attempt to use the info loaded from the query above
//however since the query has not completed i get null pointer exception
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: assuming this is a web request you can't do what you ask, if you can post some code we can help you see where you've gone wrong in your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the activity only when you receive the callback, something similar to the code below:

```
mEmployeeTable.execute(new TableQueryCallback<Employee>() {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted(List<Employee> employees, int count, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
    if (exception != null) {
      // error happened during query, deal with it appropriately
    } else {
      // store the loaded employees somewhere
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: yea i was trying to get around doing it that way for other reasons but i guess i can make it work that way by changing other lines of code. thanks